# How to fill Django database on view buttonclick

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller

I'm just learning Django, so my question might seem not worth attention, but i spent some time googling and havnt found an answer.

I have two models and a function to fill it

urls.py

```
url(r'^upd/$', update_database, name="upd")
```

views.py

```
def update_database(request):
    grabdata()



def grabdata():
    url = "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_day.geojson"
    weburl = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

    if (weburl.getcode() == 200):
        data = json.loads(weburl.read())
        EarthQuakes.objects.all().delete()
        LastGetSession.objects.all().delete()

        lastsession = LastGetSession(hand=data["metadata"]["title"])
        lastsession.save()

        for i in data["features"]:
            place = i["properties"]["place"]
            place = str.split(",")
            place = place[-1]

            time = i["properties"]["time"]
            mag = i["properties"]["mag"]
            rept = i["properties"]["felt"]
            if rept is None:
                rept = 1
            longitude = 0
            latitude = 0
            earthquake = EarthQuakes(place=place, time=time,
                                     mag=mag, rept=rept,
                                     longitude=longitude, latitude=latitude)
            earthquake.save()
```

template

```
<a id="update_button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" href="{% url 'upd' %}" >Update_database</a>
```

But i didn't get how to execute it from a view.
Or I assume there is a way to call a conroller function that calls the model function or something like that

It returns the "The view earthquake.views.update_database didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

It feels like there is one missing piece or the pazzle

Comment: You can just call it from a view. What's your current view code? BTW, you can use `bulk_create()` for faster batch inserts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Your views.py

```
def my_view(request):
    grabdata()
    return HttpResponse('Done')
```

in urls.py add a new url

```
url(r'^my-view/$', views.my_view,name='my_view')
```

in your template

```
<a href="{% url 'my_view' %}">Update</a>
```

Comment: I didnt expect it run grabdata() on server startup and it responds the "The view earthquake.views.update_database didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead." on buttonclick event/ But the rest work

Comment: A function must return a value . It is general rule in programming. return an `HttpResponse('Done')` in your view and `return` something in your function as well.

Comment: Yes. Sobir, could you possibly add the "return HttpResponse('Done')" to your answer